# Finding the Exact X-Coordinates of the Points on the Graph f(x) for Which the Tangent Line is Parallel to the Line g(x)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I cannot seem to solve the following situation:

When $f'(x)$ is equal to the slope of $g(x)$ over the interval of $\frac{\pi}{2}\le x \le \pi $ when

.

$$f'(x)=\frac{2\cos(2x)}{3\sin(2x)^{\frac{2}{3}} }$$

and $g(x)$ is defined by the equation

$$2x-3(6)^\frac{1}{3}y=0$$

.

So, my fundamental problem is with the trig functions in this case. The problem simplifies to:

$$\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{1}{6^\frac{1}{3}}=0$$

.

As always, thanks!

Comment: indeed $x=5\pi /6$ is a solution. Check the answer given below by @John Wayland Bales  where it is shown that $\cos  2x =1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g^\prime(x)=\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{6}}$ we wish to find a solution for

$$ \frac{2\cos(2x)}{3\sin(2x)^{\frac{2}{3}} }= \dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{6}}$$

in the interval $\frac{\pi}{2}\le x \le \pi$. Simplifying and cubing both sides gives

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\cos^3(2x)}{\sin^2(2x)}&=&\frac{1}{6}\\
6\cos^3(2x)-\sin^2(2x)&=&0\\
6\cos^3(2x)+\cos^2(2x)-1&=&0\\
6u^3+u^2-1&=&0\\
\end{eqnarray}
Can you finish from here, given that the polynomial has a rational zero?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The slope of your $g(x)$ is given by $$\frac{2}{3\cdot 6^{1/3}}$$ and please post your $f(x)$; maybe there is an error in the first derivative.
You must prove that this equation
$$6\cos(2x)^3+\cos(2x)^2-1=0$$ has no solutions over the given interval.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! As you can see in my final form listed in the question, I have already found the slope of g(x) and set it equal to the slope of the tangent line of $f(x)$ (e.g. $f'(x)$). I believe I fully understand the problem at hand, I have simply run into a wall with the equation itself. Also, the derivative is correct and has been verified by Wolfram Alpha and by checking points back to the original equation.

Comment: But i got no solutions in the given interval!

Comment: Neither did I! $f(x)=(sin(2x))^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: how about $x=\frac{5 \pi }{6}$ ?

Comment: This is not a solution!

Comment: @Lozenges, I manually checked all major points in quadrant II and saw that $x=\frac{5pi}{6}$ produced a zero, though I believe it is just extremely close to zero and not exact.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, How can we prove there are no solutions over this interval?